# Case statement with max()

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, case, hiveql

I have a date column `yyyy_mm_dd`. I want to create an additional column based on it with the following logic:

1. if yyyy_mm_dd = last day of month then 1
2. if yyyy_mm_dd isn't the last day of the month but is the maximum date in the dataset then 1
3. otherwise 0

I was able to come up with this, which works for part 1 and 3 of the logic:

```
select
    *,
    case
        when yyyy_mm_dd == last_day(yyyy_mm_dd) then 1
        when yyyy_mm_dd != last_day(yyyy_mm_dd) then 0
    end as last_day_of_month
from
    my_table
where
    yyyy_mm_dd is not null
```

This worked well and then I tried to add the following for the final logic:

```
when (yyyy_mm_dd == last_day(yyyy_mm_dd) or yyyy_mm_dd == max(yyyy_mm_dd)) then 1
```

However it errors saying:

> Expression not in GROUP BY key id

Is there any way I can achieve this 'last day of month or max date' flag? I don't want the max_date per group i.e. `id` but instead the absolute maximum date in the entire dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sub-query and analytic function to calculate max. `max(yyyy_mm_dd) over()` will return absolute maximum in a dataset and does not require group by.

```
select
    t.*, --list columns here
    case
        when (yyyy_mm_dd == last_day(yyyy_mm_dd) or yyyy_mm_dd == max_dt ) then 1
        else 0
    end as last_day_of_month
from
    (select t.*, max(yyyy_mm_dd) over() as max_dt from  my_table t
      where yyyy_mm_dd is not null) t;
```